# Ubuntu email: Wrong (and unexpected) postfix mapping

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have installed Ubuntu Linux 10.04 with package postfix 2.8.5-2~build0.10.04.

I have configured postfix to send email through my ISP and this works fine: I can open `mutt` and send an email to an external address (e.g. google) and the email is delivered correctly.

The next thing I wanted to do was to define a mapping so that if I send a local email, it is delivered to my address which has the form:

```
my-username@my-isp-provider.net
```

In order to do this, I followed the [postfix documentation](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#generic) and configured postfix as follows:

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic

/etc/postfix/generic:
    @my-hostname       my-username@my-isp-provider.net
    @localhost         my-username@my-isp-provider.net
```

So, if I have understood the documentation correctly, this should cause **all messages** sent to **any local user** `user-x` with the addresses `user-x@my-hostname` and `user-x@localhost` to be delivered to `my-username@my-isp-provider.net`.

Instead, I observe the following unexpected behaviour:

- If I send email to `my-username@localhost`, the message is delivered to my Linux box and not to my ISP account `my-username@my-isp-provider.net`.
- Even more strangely, my ISP administrator has sent me an email, that they are receiving messages for destination `root@my-isp-provider.net` with subject 'Subject: Anacron job 'cron.daily' on my-hostname'. I suppose this is a local notification of my Linux box that is meant for `root`, but how does this get mapped to `root@my-isp-provider.net`?

At the moment I have checked all my configuration files and I have not clue as to how I can explain this behaviour:

- Why are my messages to address `my-username@localhost` not mapped to `my-username@my-isp-provider.net` as specified in the configuration file?
- Where do these messages for `root@my-isp-provider.net` come from, if the only mapping I have specifies the complete address of the receiver (`my-username@my-isp-provider.net`) **explicitly**? So if a message for `root@locahost` gets mapped, it should be delivered to `my-username@my-isp-provider.net` and not to `root@my-isp-provider.net`.

Comment: @Anthon: Bedankt voor het edit.